Beep sound in Emacs on i3 over Ubuntu not work at all
I had the next configuration:

Emacs 27.1 install from Ubuntu servers
i3 4.20.1 (03.11.2021)
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS 64-bit

I encounter with lack of beep sound in Emacs, so:

C-g not produces any sound
M-:(beep), the same, not produces any sound
M-:(ding), the same

Any other sounds work fine over i3, on browsers, on terminal app, etc.
The sound of identical Emacs works fine directly over Ubuntu, not i3.
How can I remediate the sound?
